# Spring boot serves external HTML/javascript/css out side of web-application.jar by embedded Tomcat?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, spring-boot

I have a web application (package.jar) which runs with embedded tomcat. Now, I need to add a controller (e.g: http://localhost:8080/package/demo) which will load HTML/javascript/css **from an external folder** (e.g: /var/www/html/demo) which this web application can read files.

**I cannot add them to package.jar** as these external files can be updated later and the web-application should return all static contents as they are!

I tried to create a simple RestController which points to `/var/www/html/demo/index.html`, e.g:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String handle() throws IOException {
      File file = new File("/var/www/html/demo/index.html");
      return FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
}
```

}

The problem is it cannot request any assets (like: CSS/Javascript files) from `/var/www/html/demo/` as they don't exist as resources inside package.jar (e.g: http://localhost:8080/package/assets/js/config.js)

Do you have any suggestions to do it? Thanks

Comment: The right approach is to deploy the static content in webserver and use javascript frameworks like jquery angular js etc to communicate with webservice deployed in app server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the idea is it needs to add static resource when Spring Boot starts like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ... 

    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/demo/**").
                          addResourceLocations("file:///var/www/html/demo/");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then, access http://localhost:8080/package/demo will show the html page with all static content.